# Excluding a category from next and previous post links

Tags: categories, exclude

I am trying to figure out the code to exclude a category from my next and previous post links.

My code for the next and previous is as follows:

```
<div class="next_prev_cont">
                    <div class="left">
                         <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i>Previous post</i><br />%title'); ?> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                         <?php next_post_link('%link', '<i>Next post</i><br />%title'); ?> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!--//next_prev_cont-->
```

I believe I need to use the following:
    $excluded_terms = '4835'

4835 being the cat ID, but I'm not sure how to implement it?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` functions have parameteres as follows -

- **`$format`** *(string)* - You've already included this.
- **`$link`** *(string)* - You've already included this.
- **`$in_same_term = false`** *(boolean)* - Whether or not all linked posts should be within the same taxonomy term. Chances are this should be false if you are looking to exclude a single term.
- **`$excluded_terms = ''`** *(string|array)* - The terms to exclude, as a comma seperated string or an array of integers.
- **`$taxonomy = 'category'`** *(string)* - Only required if `$in_same_cat = true`.

So to get your links working as you desire you should do this -

```
<?php $excluded_terms = '4835'; ?>
<div class="next_prev_cont">
    <div class="left">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i>Previous post</i><br />%title', false, $excluded_terms); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', '<i>Next post</i><br />%title', false, $excluded_terms); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

I recommend you take a few moment to read the related function referneces for these two functions -

- `next_post_link()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link
- `previous_post_link()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link